# AD Management via powershell on 2008 enterprise

Tags: windows-server-2008, powershell, windows

windows server 2008 enterprise, without hyper-v x64

We have a client server that I am trying to automate some functions on using power shell directly on the server. I have the gateway service installed, and can manage via RSAT from a client machine, but I want to have the cmdlets on the server itself so I may schedule the task to run locally.

Is there any way to actually get the AD powershell tools installed on the server, or will this HAVE to be done from a client machine?

If so, are there any viable reasons to not do this?
If not, why is it not possible? (just because it is not supported, or is there a technical barrier I do not understand that prevents it?)

Comment: I really am not sure what you are asking here...  You mention hyper-v, but what does hyper-v have to do with anything?  What do you mean by 'we have a client server'.  Is it really 2008, or is it 2008r2?  Is the remote setup as core, or what?  Is that 2008 server a domain controller within the domain, or just a member server?

Comment: just stating the version as listed in the system properties. As for "client server" = "server belonging to a client" (sorry that was a bit ambiguous) The server is the only DC, it services a factory floor where all of the clients are machines, not humans. We are trying to automate some of the tasks on the AD so it can exist with minimal oversight, however the only machine I can guarantee to always be on is the server itself. I have no control over upgrading the server or replacing it. End game is to schedule .ps scripts using Get-AD**** cmdlets locally on the 2008 DC machine.

Comment: I don't have a 'Server 2008' can you see if the AD powershell feature is available?  Here is my screen from a 2008r2 box.  http://i.stack.imgur.com/SuGbx.png

Comment: It is not, and when you install the active directory management gateway service it does not add them either. Just the ability to now manage that 2008 server from a W7 with RSAT installed or 2008R2 server. That is where I am stuck, it will let me manage that server from a client station, I want to do the same thing ON the server and need to know if it is even possible without an insane unstable hack at it.

Comment: Well I suspect that it is time for you to strongly think about upgrading your server...

Comment: well hence my comment "I have no control over upgrading the server or replacing it." it belongs to a client, and the call to replace it is not mine. I just need to work with it for this job...

Comment: Well you likely have to give up on using the PS *verb-ADcommands* and use the older APIs then.  You can certainly still use all the old 2000/2003 ADSI stuff, though it is a big pain to do.  Either that or tell your client they are not supportable.

Comment: I can support them, and am currently doing so via powershell and string parsing output from the ds* commands. But for what we are doing this is an extremely unwieldy way to do what I could do much more simply with the AD cmdlets. Thank you for the input though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said, the native AD cmdlets module is not available on Windows Server 2008 (non-R2). What I have done in a similar situation is to import a PS session from a domain controller where the AD module is installed, and then use that. For example:

```
function Get-ActiveDirectorySession {
    param(
        [string]$Server = '2008R2.domain.controller'
    )
    $session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $Server
    Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {Import-Module ActiveDirectory}
    return $session
}
```

Then on the machine where I want to run the AD cmdlets but don't have them installed, I just load the function defined above and run:

```
Import-PSSession -Session (Get-ActiveDirectorySession) -Module ActiveDirectory | Out-Null
```

This will give you a virtual copy of the AD cmdlets that you can run locally. You can do `Get-Help Import-PSSession -Full` for more information on how this works.

I don't know if this method would work remoting into a Windows 7 client machine with the AD cmdlets installed -- I think there might be two-hop issues when actually connecting to a domain controller in that case. I hope this helps.

Comment: Just wanted to say thank you for that excellent suggestion. I had a nasty reaction to a be sting and have been down for a while, but this is in my cheat sheet repository for sure now.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to install the following on your 2008 box:

.NET Framework 4.0 ([Download](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17851))

Windows Management Framework 3.0 ([Download](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34595))

Comment: These are already both installed, this puts me up to powershell 3 according to $PSVersionTable, but does not include the AD cmdlets.

Comment: Unfortunately the Active Directory module for Windows PowerShell is only available on Windows 7 (as part of RSAT) and Windows Server 2008 R2.
The Active Directory Management Gateway Service is a web-service for down-level operatings ystem which the Active Directory module for PowerShell can communicate with.

Answer (score 1):

You just can't use the AD cmdlets on systems older than Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2; they are not available.

You can try [Quest's (free) set of AD PowerShell cmdlets](http://www.quest.com/powershell/activeroles-server.aspx); they have been quite popular for a while, before Microsoft implemented its own solution.